# Excel Macro ordering PivotItems

Tags: excel, vba, date, loops, pivot-table

Background:
I have a pivot table in Excel with "Date" as an XLColumn field.
The source data is always changing and I noticed when new data would be added the pivot table would NOT order the pivot items for filtering by date. It would add it to the end as a string. I have since changed the source data and made sure the Date column are indeed dates.

1st Thing:
I need to order the date pivot items programmatically in VBA. That is a user can filter the dates which are listed in order even when new dates are added (older to more recent).

2nd Thing:
 I want to loop through the date pivot items, showing the the 1st and 2nd, then 2nd and 3rd, then 3rd and 4th etc.

Something like:

```
-code that hides all pivot items
Pf.pivotitems (i).visible = true (12/04/2012)
Pf.pivotitems(i + 1).visible = true (19/04/2012)
i = i + 1
```

This has been returning an error on me, can't set visible property of pivot item.

Thanks,

Any further information required please ask.

Ramify

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

> 1st Thing: I need to order the date pivot items programmatically in VBA. That is a user can filter the dates which are listed in order even when new dates are added (older to more recent).

```
'~~> Change Sheet1 with the relevant sheet name
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    '~~> Change PivotTable1 and DateField to the respective pivot and field name.
    .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("DateField").AutoSort xlAscending, "DateField"
End With
```

> 2nd Thing: I want to loop through the date pivot items, showing the the 1st and 2nd, then 2nd and 3rd, then 3rd and 4th etc.

```
Pf.PivotItems(i).Visible= True
Pf.PivotItems(i + 1).Visible= True
```